# How would I correctly cite one of Polybius' Histories

Tags: citations

I want to cite one of Polybius's Histories for a paper I'm writing, but I'm confused as to how the citation will work due to processing through multiple works.

Specifically I want to cite this: https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Polybius/1*.html

Would I cite only the original work by Polybius himself? Would I cite just the most recent source being this specific webpage? Or would I cite **Vol. I of the Loeb Classical Library edition, 1922**, as that is where part of Polybius's work is published that the webpage link reproduces (It's referenced at the top of the link's page).

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This would be governed first of all by the customs of your discipline. With historical texts like this, it is helpful to know the edition you were using, especially if you were to not cite the original text but a translation. But even if you use the original, knowing the edition might be helpful as a book that has been passed on by copying by hand might have (or almost certainly has) textual variations.